# Why do I need to add curly braces to the action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Action creators:

```
export const addTodoCustom = function (text) {
    return {
        type: "ADD_TODO",
        id: nextTodoId++,
        text
    };
};
```

Right statement:

```
import * as actions from "../actions"
import AddTodo from "../components/AddTodo";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {addTodoCustom} from "../actions";


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addTodoCustom})(AddTodo);
```

Wrong statement:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, addTodoCustom)(AddTodo);
```

Why do I need to add curly braces to the action creator in React with Redux? What is the syntax of Javascript?

**Update:**

Sample Project:
https://github.com/gongzelong0718/redux-quickstart-tutorial/tree/question

Note: please check out the branch `question`

[image: Wrong statement runtime error screenshot]

**Update 2**

Here is what I thought:

I check the JavaScript ES6 syntax: **Enhanced Object Literal Value Shorthand**

The right statement is equals to:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {a: addTodoCustom})(AddTodo);
```

So why do I need to use `{a: addTodoCustom}` instead of `addTodoCustom`?

Comment: Please check https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: Why did you think you *wouldn't* need braces? Have you tried reading a tutorial to learn the syntax of the language you're trying to use? Read the API docs to see what connect expects? That's just an *object literal* with *shorthand property names*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you help check the update and my answer?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra Could you help check the update and my answer?

Comment: It's not `{a: addTodoCustom}`, it's `{addTodoCustom: addTodoCustom}`. Also your answer seems to be additional information for the question. Consolidate this to one coherent question, which I don't think is about *syntax* or *curly braces* at all; it's basically why doesn't connect accept a action creator *or* object whose values are action creators.

Comment: connect second param takes either function or object. if you pass function then connect function will call that function with paramter dispatch. if you want to pass object i suggest you import all action `import * as allActions from '../action';` and in use `export default connect(mapStateToProps, allActions)(AddTodo);`

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra I intended use a to differentiate the key and value of a map object.  I know the usage. But I do wonder why I have to add _curly braces_, because Iike I mentioned in the answer, MHO, addTodoCustom is a funtion which is a action creator, while {a, addTodoCustom} is an Object. Both way should work. Why I could not pass addTodoCustom, a function as the parameter?

Comment: if you pass function in second param in connect then connect will call that function with dispatch as param like in your case connect will call `addTodoCustom(dispatch)` which expect a object in return, that object is pass to your component as props.

if you want function then you can pass like 
`connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch)=> ({a: (...args)=> dispatch(addTodoCustom(args))}))(AddTodo)`

Comment: @FrancisBacon, where is your `mapStateToProps` function? That is missing here.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to import your `connect` function before you can use it like so:

`import { connect } from 'react-redux';`

With the `connect` helper you can pass up to two arguments to it, the first one being either `null` or `mapStateToProps`, but you have to create that function first. Its purpose is to take your global state object (application state), the thing that sits inside your Redux store and map it or take some properties off the state object and provide them as props to your component of `AddTodo`.

I think you are also missing your `payload` property, so instead you want your action creator to look like so:

```
export const addTodoCustom = text => {
   return {
     type: "ADD_TODO",
     id: nextTodoId++,
     payload: text
   };
};
```

It would have been helpful I think for you to also post your reducer, since this is all part of the Redux system.

Now back to your `connect()` function, the second argument would be the action creator that you want to bind to that component which would be `addTodoCustom`. Please ensure that your relative path to it in your `import` statement is correct.

Once having done all the above then this `export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addTodoCustom})(AddTodo);` should work as long as you have your `mapStateToProps` function. If not then you need to write it like this: `export default connect(null, {addTodoCustom})(AddTodo);`

You never showed the contents of your `AddTodo` component, and one can only assume by the use of `mapStateToProps` that it is a class-based component, it would be helpful if you shared that code as well.

Answer (score -1):

Checking the source code of (bindActionCreators)[https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9d3273846aa8906d38890c410b62fb09a4992018/src/bindActionCreators.ts]. We know

```
export default function bindActionCreators(
  actionCreators: ActionCreator<any> | ActionCreatorsMapObject,
  dispatch: Dispatch
) {
  if (typeof actionCreators === 'function') {
    return bindActionCreator(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }

  if (typeof actionCreators !== 'object' || actionCreators === null) {
    throw new Error(
      `bindActionCreators expected an object or a function, instead received ${
        actionCreators === null ? 'null' : typeof actionCreators
      }. ` +
        `Did you write "import ActionCreators from" instead of "import * as ActionCreators from"?`
    )
  }

  const boundActionCreators: ActionCreatorsMapObject = {}
  for (const key in actionCreators) {
    const actionCreator = actionCreators[key]
    if (typeof actionCreator === 'function') {
      boundActionCreators[key] = bindActionCreator(actionCreator, dispatch)
    }
  }
  return boundActionCreators
}
```

So **the final reason** is that we need to pass a map as the 1st parameter of bindActionCreators. So we need to pass a object with key and value. {a: addTodoCustom}, **ActionCreatorsMapObject** like what is defined in source code, not a addTodoCustom which is a object and also a function

**But there is another question:**

Why does it execute the following codes when I pass `addTodoCustom`

```
export default function bindActionCreators(
  actionCreators: ActionCreator<any> | ActionCreatorsMapObject,
  dispatch: Dispatch
) {
  if (**typeof actionCreators === 'function'**) {
    return bindActionCreator(actionCreators, dispatch)
  }
```

and then call `bindActionCreator(actionCreators, dispatch)`

```
function bindActionCreator<A extends AnyAction = AnyAction>(
  actionCreator: ActionCreator<A>,
  dispatch: Dispatch
) {
  return function(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
    return dispatch(actionCreator.apply(this, args))
  }
}
```

I read the doc https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-the-mapdispatchtoprops-function-with-bindactioncreators

> bindActionCreators accepts two parameters:
>
> A function (an action creator) or an object (each field an action
>   creator)

It says I can pass a function.

IMHO, addTodoCustom is a funtion
{a, addTodoCustom} is an Object.

Correct me if I am wrong.